# Why would echo $shell come up with a blank output?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

According to O'Reilly Linux pocket guide by Daniel J. Barrett, the command `echo $shell` should print out the current shell in use.

When I ran that command from the terminal I got a blank line. My understanding is that there should be a shell running if you have a terminal open, therefore I'm confused why it would print out blank.

```
raven# echo $shell

raven#
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. While it doesn't affect readability too much in this particular case, please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variable names are case-sensitive. The [convention is](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) that environment variables have all-uppercase names. You should type

```bash
echo $SHELL
```

instead. As noted by @StephenKitt, this is also the command actually stated in the book.

As a general note, using `echo` to print the content of shell variables is [becoming discouraged in favor of `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/377345), as also noted in the anwer by @Stéphane Chazelas.

Comment: Thank you. I will make note to be more aware of lower and upper case.

Comment: @Dmagamon You're welcome. It is one of the nice shell pitfalls. One consequence is the recommendation that it is advisable that you don't choose all-uppercase names for shell variables in your own scripts unless you want to export them as environment variables, in order to prevent accidentally overwriting existing shell variables (which might make your scripts stop working correctly).

Comment: @StephenKitt, but that book is still wrong (beside the missing quotes and usage of `echo`) if it claims that gives you the shell currently in use without stating the conditions under which that might be true.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, it is wrong — it says “To see if you’re running bash, type: `echo $SHELL`”...

Comment: It's wronger than that. If I am in `bash`, and run `ksh` at the command line, `ksh` inherits `SHELL` in its environment, so it then claims to be `/bin/bash` too.

Answer (score 3):

Only the `csh` / `tcsh` shells set the `$shell` variable. So you'd only get the path of a shell with that `echo $shell` command if run from one those shells¹, maybe you found that in a section of that book that talks about those.

`login` or other login managers set the `SHELL` *environment* variable to your login shell (the shell mentioned in the `passwd` database for your account), which shells will invariably map to their corresponding `$SHELL` variable and it's the environment variable you want to set to your preferred shell for things like terminal emulators or `vi` to start it instead of your login shell.

But that's not necessarily the shell that is *currently in use*.

It would be the case if you have started your terminal emulator in an environment where that `$SHELL` variable had not been modified since login and your terminal emulator is not otherwise configured to start a different shell (or other command) from the one stored in `$SHELL`, and a different shell has not been started or the `$SHELL` variable modified as part of your `$SHELL` shell startup sequence.

There is no shell variable that will tell you which shell is in use regardless of the shell though beside (t)csh's `$shell`, there's `bash`'s `$BASH` or `$BASH_VERSION`/`$BASH_VERSINFO`, `zsh`'s `$ZSH_VERSION`, `$KSH_VERSION` in some `ksh` implementations, `${.sh.version}` in ksh93, `$YASH_VERSION` in `yash` which can help you tell which shell you're running.

On Linux, you can also do `readlink "/proc/$$/exe"` to get the path of the shell interpreter with those shells where `$$` expands to the pid of the process that executed the interpreter (Bourne-like, csh-like; see `$fish_pid` in `fish`, `$pid` in `rc`-like shells).

More portably, `sh -c 'ps -o comm= -p "$PPID"'` will give you the name of the parent process of `sh`, which should be running the shell *currently in use*, and the name of that process should be derived from the basename of the shell interpreter executable. All common shells should interpret that code the same, an all systems in scope of this site should have a `sh` and `ps` commands that can understand that.

To print the contents of a variable followed by a newline in Bourne-like shells, the syntax is:

```
printf '%s\n' "$SHELL"
```

Or in `csh`:

```
printf '%s\n' $SHELL:q
```

Or in `rc`-like or `fish` or `zsh` shells:

```
printf '%s\n' $SHELL
```

not <strike>`echo $SHELL`</strike> (though when you don't know which shell you're running, that's probably a good enough approximation that should work in most shells in most cases).

To know which is your login shell, as stored in the `passwd` database, on many systems, you can do (Bourne syntax):

```
getent -- passwd "$LOGNAME" | cut -d: -f7
```

Or on systems without a `getent` utility:

```
perl -le 'print((getpwnam getlogin)[8])'
```

---

<sup>¹ but only if `$shell` doesn't contain wildcard characters, and could also be mangled by `echo` which can't output arbitrary data</sup>